# How do you make a bot that sends embed welcome messages?

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

I currently am having trouble running this code it used to stop the bot/replit when a person joins the bot/replit now it declares it as an empty message

```
let Discord = require("discord.js");
let client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
  client.user.setPresence({ 'activity': { name: "Test}})
})

client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
 const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
 .setTitle(`Welcome ${member.user.tag}!`)
 .setDescription(`You are member ${member.guild.memberCount}`)
  const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name ===   'welcome-channel')
  channel.send({
    embeds: [embed]
  })
})

client.login("")
```

Comment: Is there still an issue with this question? Could not get a clear view of the current state when reading the comments on the first answer to this question.

Also, your code in your question has a typo on `setPresence`, you are missing `"` from the other end of the `Test` word.

Comment: no its running good now by defining the channel in a different way

Answer (score 0):

You can use `client.on('guildMemberAdd')` and this for the embed =>

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Welcome ${member.user.tag}!`)
    .setDescription(`You are member ${member.guild.memberCount}!`)
  const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'welcome-channel')
  channel.send({
    embeds: [embed]
  })
})
```

Comment: got referenceerror MessageEmbed is not defined when people join
let Discord = require("discord.js");
let client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
  client.user.setPresence({ 'activity': { name: "test"}})
})

client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  const embed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`Welcome ${member.user.tag}!`)
    .setDescription(`You are member ${member.guild.memberCount}!`)
  const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name ===   'welcome-channel')
  channel.send({
    embeds: [embed]
  })
})
client.login("<my token is here>")

Comment: Then change it to `const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle(\`Welcome ${member.user.tag}!\`).setDescription(\`You are member ${member.guild.memberCount}!\`)`

Comment: still isn't working it just rejects ps sorry im new.
too long so im shorten this first part could not shorten empty message
(node:1049) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
then a warns of unhandled promise rejections

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: ya sure ill edit my post / original message

Comment: Just a note, in your question, you can actually insert a code block by clicking on the button with the greater than and lesser than sign. It will help since it is more readable

Comment: In your embed, you should change the `.setTitle()` to `.setTitle(\`Welcome ${member.user.tag}!\`)` since you have not written the backticks in it and in the `.setDescription()` as well, you need to change it to `.setDescription(\`You are member ${member.guild.memberCount}\`)`

Comment: thank you for that note btw and i had them but i forgot to add it in the text but it should be easier to see now

Comment: Which version of `discord.js` do you have?

Comment: the version of discord.js is 13.6.0

Comment: When you are setting your presence in the `client.on('ready')`, is `activity` in single quotes or is it like that here only?

Comment: Activity is in single quotes

Comment: Try removing them and see